# Rails 5 Api - how to view and reduce server response time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, rails-api, netflix

I am generating nested json objects for 300 records (GET request), all eager loaded from various tables, using fast_jsonapi gem from Netflix.

The time spent on ActiveRecord is a magnitude lower than previously when I used AMS. However the total time is not drastically improved, taking 1484ms as shown below:

```
  1.080000   0.020000   1.100000 (  1.421109)
Completed 200 OK in 1484ms (Views: 9.7ms | ActiveRecord: 51.3ms)
```

Views and ActiveRecord are fast - only 60ms, so what is the vast majority of time spent on??

How can I investigate this?

Comment: Are you using anything to instrument your app? Where is it taking the most time to process?

EDIT - ah, just read your comment. Looks like ActiveSupport has something: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html

Meanwhile for services, there's www.skylight.io, www.newrelic.com, and https://scoutapp.com/